# Powershell. Difference between piping commands and using Foreach-Object

Tags: windows, powershell, pipeline, foreach-object

Sorry if this question is already been answered, I could find similar questions but not the exact one I need to ask.

Let's take two examples:

```
 1. Get-Process -name msedge,putty | Stop-Process
 2. Get-Process -name msedge,putty | Foreach-Object {Stop-Process $_}
```

Both are doing the same operation. What about the methods used in each one? Are they the same in the sense that the first example just omits the `Foreach-Object` construction for the sake of code readability/aesthetics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example requires the Cmdlet to support binding of the relevant parameters via the pipeline. In your case `Stop-Process` will bind the Process object from the pipeline to it's `-InputObject` parameter.

You can check that using  `get-help stop-process -Parameter *` and see which parameters have "Accept pipeline input?" set to true.

In case a Cmdlet does not support the binding of the relevant parameters values you can wrap `ForEach-Object` around it, like you did in the second example. This way you use the automatic variable `$_` to bind the current pipeline object (or information that you derive from it) "manually" to the corresponding parameter.

What approach should you use if a Cmdlet supports the binding of parameter values from the pipeline? That unfortunately depends. It is possible to write a Cmdlet that behaves differently, depending on how the parameter values are bound. Let me illustrate this point:

```
function Test-BindingFoo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]
        $InputParameter
    )
    
    begin {
        Write-Host "[BEGIN]"
    }
    
    process {
        foreach ($value in $InputParameter) {
            Write-Host "The current value is: $value"
        }
    }
    
    end {
        Write-Host "[END]"
    }
}
```

If you execute this Cmdlet using the pipeline binding the Begin block of the function is executed exactly once:

```
❯ "foo1", "foo2" | Test-BindingFoo
[BEGIN]
The current value is: foo1
The current value is: foo2
[END]
```

If you use `ForEach-Object` the Begin block is executed every time an object passes through the pipeline:

```
❯ "foo1", "foo2" | ForEach-Object { Test-BindingFoo $_ }
[BEGIN]
The current value is: foo1
[END]
[BEGIN]
The current value is: foo2
[END]
```

In well implemented Cmdlets the difference here should not matter. But I found it useful to be aware of what happens inside a Cmdlet when parameteres are passed in in the ways that we have discussed here.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed and useful answer.

Comment: No worries, we are all happy to help here. You can also mark the answer that you feel answers your question best as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too and use the kill method on the process object (operation statement):

```
Get-Process msedge,putty | Foreach-Object kill
# or
Get-Process msedge,putty | Foreach-Object -membername kill
```

Comment: This is just another way to write OP's 2nd example: `kill` is not a method but an alias for `stop-process`, and `foreach-object` different syntax (cfr. _Operation statement_ )was introduced in Powershell 3.0, but it's not semantically different.

Comment: @MikeL'Angelo Yes it's a coincidence that kill is a stop-process alias, but if you set `set-psdebug -Trace 2`, you'll see that foreach-object is calling method `void Kill()`.

Comment: you are right, it calls the method, nice to know! But, it's not a coincidence, it's an explicit parameter which evidently takes precedence with respect to the `process{scriptblock}` invocation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)

Comment: @MikeL'Angelo It's a coincidence that kill is both an alias for stop-process, and a method name from the process object.  There's no scriptblock argument in this case. so this is a different parameter set.

Comment: yes, coincidence comes into play because they both are called the same (the process _method_ and the _cmdlet_ ).  What I mean is, `foreach-object` does offer a specific _parameter set_ which has the `-membername` parameter. When calling `foreach-object` without explicit parameters as in your example, this parameter set (the one with the `-membername` parameter) gets called first because of internal precedence. This way, `kill` is treated as a method as opposed to a cmdlet.

Comment: @MikeL'Angelo It's not precedence, but the type of the argument.  'kill' is a string type on the command line, vs {  } which is a scriptblock type.  So one parameter sets fits more than the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234576/discussion-between-mike-langelo-and-js2010).